# How to use Koala Facebook gem and save each data element to DB in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to save each returned value from Koala to db and so on... so far I've got my model connecting to Facebook, authorization, etc... however, no matter what I do I can't save the share count from the returned hash.

For example; my modem pulls the home timeline like so;

```
def self.pull

   fbstory_pull = current_user.facebook.get_connection("me", "home")
   fbstory_pull.each do |s|
      something.create({facebook_shares: s["shares"]["count"]})
   end

end
```

I get bunch of errors, if I try and do the same but this time like so; for facebook_author_name, it works fine;

```
def self.pull
   fbstory_pull = current_user.facebook.get_connection("me", "home")
   fbstory_pull.each do |s|
      something.create({facebook_author_name: s["from"]["name"]})
   end
end
```

I noticed that `["from"]["name"]` sits under `data` using the Facebook graph explorer, and `["shares"]["count"]` sits else where on the return hash feed.

Comment: my `fbstory_pull.each do |story|` returns all variables including the post `id` and I can use something like this `shares = @graph.get_object('post_id', :fields => "shares")["shares"]["count"]` to define `shares` but how do I pull which should be `story["id"]` and put it in placement of `'post_id'`

Comment: them I would of course do `something.create({share_count: shares})` to store the value into DB